# Solr dynamic field to return the number of values in a multivalue field

Tags: solr

I have the following multi value field:

```
<arr name="groupId">
    <str>1001</str>
    <str>1002</str>
    <str>1003</str>
    <str>1009</str>
    <str>1010</str>
</arr>
```

How can I use a dynamic field to tell me the count of values in that array?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a dynamic field, use an [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor), specifically [CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html).